# Ninja Build Failing for Azure Kinetic Github Repo

Tags: ninja, azurekinect

I am trying to configure the Azure Kinetic to allow C programming scripts based off the following repo:

https://github.com/microsoft/Azure-Kinect-Sensor-SDK

The build instructions include the following line:

```
joshy91@joshy91-Alienware-Aurora-R9:~/Downloads/Azure-Kinect-Sensor-SDK/build$ ninja
```

I get the following error message

> ninja: error: '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so', needed by    'bin/viewer_opengl', missing and no known rule to make it*

I'm using an Ubuntu 18.04 OS and I've tried installing several lib packages and creating several links to no success

Answer (score 1):

As per their building.md: you need to clone the repo instead of downing the ZIP.

> If you need to build from source, you have to clone the repository instead of downloading the Zip file to ensure all the submodule dependencies in place.

Building from the clone will download and build the external project dependencies.